# how do i clear up space because my phone is almost full?

Tags: insufficient-memory, huawei, huawei-ascend-y330

Can i sweep the storage. Is this data i don't want or the data that runs my phone. Not sure exactly what my huawei phone stores in storage. Whats miscellaneous?

Comment: Pointer: Check our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for hints :)

Answer (score 0):

The storage you sweep refers to stuff like cache or minor app memory. Most of the time, these are things you don't need on your phone that store excessive memory in order to make the phone run a little faster.

Miscellaneous refers to the **files** on your phone (think of as a file manager) and stores things like your downloaded files from the internet, movies you downloaded, and really anything in your internal storage directory. Some of these files (like .android) are necessary to run your device. The things you installed from chrome or app data only effect those parts of the device and are therefore safe to clean.

Most of your storage is probably made up of apps, music, and photos. I would remove some of those in order to save the most data. For photos, use google photos and put them on the cloud instead of storage if you take a lot of them. This way, you will have the most storage as you can.